# Detect if a user logged in or logged out

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication

I have a launch daemon that will need to spawn a tray icon in a users session on OSX. My current problem is: is there a way to get an event whenever a user logs in or logs out? Similar to using logind or consolekit on linux.

Comment: A LaunchDaemon automatically gets run at login, and should be killed at logout. What problem are you solving beyond that? If your tray is a LaunchDaemon, the fact that it's running is a strong hint that the user just logged in. Do you need to separate that from other cases of running the daemon?

Comment: I thought a LoginDaemon would behave this way? I have a gloabal service that listens to incomming connections and only accepts them when a user is logged in and the tray is visible... But the connection must be held the whole time as there is some other traffic going through that.

Comment: Sorry; it's been a couple of years since I built one of these. Flipped daemons and agents in my head. I'll answer below.

Comment: After doing lots of research, I think this is exactly what I needed: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1133/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

The tool you want is a LaunchAgent. LaunchAgents are automatically launched when a user logs in, and shut down when the log out. If you also have a LaunchDaemon, you can use a LaunchAgent to communicate to it from the user context. See [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) for full details and how to set it up. Make sure to look at XPC services as well (in the same doc) to understand one way to communicate between processes. You can also use loopback networking, but XPC is more powerful and preferred when appropriate.

If you're building this kind of thing, you definitely want to read the entire [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) and also [TN2083: Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html). That tech note is probably the most important document you'll read for this kind of problem. OS X is not like Linux (or BSD) in this regard.

Comment: This is not what I want. I think I just explained it a bit bullshitty what I need. The Service I need will run all the time holding a connection. But a certain type of connection will only be accepted if a user is logged in and a tray icon is running. Thats why I need to detect logins.